# modify simulink model at run time

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am new to simulink and I wonder if I can modify simulink model at run time. I am building a model for homes exchange data using goto and from blocks, can i chang the goto tag value at run time, or can i add a new input to bus creator at run time.

I will appreciate any replay, it is urgent.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot change the topology of the model while the simulation is running.
You can only change parameters and signal data.

(Note that GoTo and From blocks  are "virtual" -- they are really just for graphical convenience so that you don't have to draw a line that might make your model messy.
Under the hood those blocks act as it they are connected by a line.)

You'll need to figure out how to do the data transfer another way.

Comment: I am sorry to disturb you, but is there a way in simulink to transfer data?

Comment: How to correctly set up blocks to communicate with each other changes depending on what is being modeled (continuous time, discrete time, event driven, etc...)  You haven't provided anywhere near enough information to even make a guess at what is required.